# undefined method error in helper for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to call a global method in a file in the `lib/` directory from a model. I've already tried with concerns and the problem persists.

The app is developed in Ruby on Rails 5.2.1 and Ruby 2.5.3

```rb
# Expense model
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  include Helpers
  def self.quantity_this_month
    select { |e| year_month(e.date) == year_month(Date.today) 
     }.count
  end
end
```

```rb
# Helper in lib/ directory
module Helpers
  def year_month(date)
    date.strftime('%Y/%m')
  end
end
```

```rb
# in console
Expense.quantity_this_month
```

Implementing the code of the helper directly in the model method gives the expected result, but right now it shows this error:

```
undefined method `year_month' for #<Class:0x00007f2f6f0e4b88>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `extend` instead of `include` because the method you want to call it from is a *class method*.

Also, just a side note, your `self.quantity_this_month` loads *all* the Expense records into memory, but it's possible to do the date filtering and counting all within a single SQL query. The below is how it's done in MySQL, this might be slightly different with other databases:

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  extend Helpers # <~~~~~~~ changed to extend
  def self.quantity_this_month
    where(
      "DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m') = ?",
      year_month(Date.today)
    ).count
  end
end
```

Comment: Genius!!! it's working, thanks for the improvement in my code,i'm using postgres, to format the date: to_char(date, 'YYYY/MM')